# PHP String Comparison Issue

Tags: php

I can not figure out where I'm going wrong.

I've done so many string comparisons before and this one just refuses to work, the code is below;

```
$comparison_string = 'Transfers';

if ($location_name_chk == 0)
    $location_name_chk = 'Not_Transfers_Location';

echo $location_name_chk;
if(strcasecmp($location_name_chk, $comparison_string) == 1) {
    echo 'Location not Transfers';
    die();
```

Essentially, it's not getting to the part where it's comparing the strings.

I can 100% confirm that `$comparison string == Transfers` and that `$location_name_chk == Not_Transfers_Location` as the `echo $location_name_chk` does show correctly in the Network Display tab.

Any ideas? I have tried a range of different ideas that are in other questions, but to no avail (trim, strcasecmp etc)

Comment: `strcasecmp()` returns `0` when the strings are equal.

Comment: It returns a positive number when the first string is higher than the second string, it returns a negative number when the first string is lower.

Comment: Hi Barmar, what do you mean by higher sorry? The second piece of code isn't being reached either.

`else if(strcasecmp($location_name_chk, $comparison_string) == 0) {
     echo "Location is Transfers";
    }`

Comment: He's saying change your test to `== 0` instead of `== 1`. When the strings are the same you'll get `0` returned.

Comment: @MichaelNoyce `bbb` is higher than `aaa`.

Comment: It's like dictionary order. If the word would be later in the dictionary, it's higher.

Answer (score 1):

*Sometime* (in fact, **always**), [reading the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) helps a lot.

> strcasecmp ( string $str1 , string $str2 ) : int
>
> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

Some examples :

```
strcasecmp("abc", "Abc"); // 0

strcasecmp("abc", "Abcd"); // negative number (-1)

strcasecmp("abc", "Abcdefg"); // negative number (-4)

strcasecmp("Abcd", "abc"); // positive number (1)

strcasecmp("Abcdefg", "abc"); // positive number (4)

strcasecmp("abc", "def"); // negative number (-3)

strcasecmp("def", "abc"); // positive number (3)
```

---

In your code, change this :

```
if(strcasecmp($location_name_chk, $comparison_string) == 1)
```

To this

```
//     Notice this --------------------------------------V
if(strcasecmp($location_name_chk, $comparison_string) == 0)
```